# How to "open all" examples in local help pages for Mathematica 12?

Tags: documentation

Sorry if this is easy to find, but I am not able to find it.

When I do `?DSolve` and select `local` help (this is new in V12), the help page that comes up says there are 157 examples. But below it only 2 basic examples are shown.

How does one open or see all 157 examples at once to browse them all? Clicking on `Examples` only closes the basic examples page.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is one supposed to manually open each link in the list below and search each looking for these examples?

Now if I select the `web` version of the help, I see this on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And it works. Clicking `open all` it opens all examples there. I did not count there are 157 ofcourse, but at least all examples are on same page on the web.

How can one view all 157 examples of `DSolve` in the local help page?

V 12, windows 10.

Comment: Szabolcs's method has worked in *M* for ages, so I removed the V12 tag.

Comment: Ref: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/OpenAllSubgroups.html (or search for ["open all"](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=open%20all) or ["open all groups"](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=open%20all%20groups) in the documentation center)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit -> Select All, then Cell -> Grouping -> Open All Subgroups.

On Mac, Command-A then Shift-Command-{. You can look up the Windows shortcuts in the menu.